# CNTK C# Merge Inputs to a single Output

Tags: c#, deep-learning, actor, cntk

I'm trying to implement an Actor-Critic model with CNTK C#.

Having spent days searching half the internet, you're kinda my last hope :)

I'm trying to "combine" two Input Variables (two matrices with one dimension each of the same size) to a single output of one dimension double the size.

So for example, let's take a look at the follwing code:

```
var input1 = Variable.InputVariable(new[] { 9 }, DataType.Float, "input1");
var input2 = Variable.InputVariable(new[] { 9 }, DataType.Float, "input2");

var combined = Function.Combine(new[] {input1, input2});
// The following throws error
// var combinesVariable = new Variable(combined);
```

which throws the exception:

```
A Function instance 'Composite(Combine): Input('input1', [9], [*, #]), Input('input2', [9], [*, #]) -> Input('input1', [9], [*, #]), Input('input2', [9], [*, #])' with more than one output cannot be implicitly converted to a Variable.
```

Ultimately, I would like to end up with a Variable with (maybe) two inputs of dimension size [9] and one output of dimension size [18].

Answer (score 1):

Try [Splice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/cntk-library-managed-api) This should allow you to concatenate variables along a chosen axis. The combine is for creating new functions from a pair of functions so they can be seen in the graph as one step, I think.